# How to conditionally style CircleMarkers in React Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, events, styling, react-leaflet

So, like some other users, I've recently bumped into the problem of adding React functionality to popups on the React Leaflet GeoJSON Layer. After reading several posts here on SO, the issue apparently comes down to a mismatch between using native Leaflet features and the features abstracted out with the React Leaflet implementation. In using the native Leaflet methods, the popup binding only accepts a string, which prevents adding JSX or additional interaction.

In abandoning the GeoJSON component, I'm also losing the `onEachFeature` function which is the main way to easily style and add events to the layer. In refactoring my app to use Circle markers, I can't seem to figure out how to conditionally style the individual markers based on the feature's properties. It seems that the GeoJSON Layer `pathOptions` prop doesn't seem to accept a function like so:

```
import { CircleMarker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import PopupContent from "./PopupContent";

const CircleMarkerLayer = ({ data }) => {
    return  data.features.map((feature) => {
    const { coordinates } = feature.geometry
    const markerStyles = function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.type) {
            case 'Sticker': return {color: '#a50026'};
            case 'Mural':   return {color: '#d73027'};
            case 'Marker':   return {color: '#f46d43'};
            case 'Characters':   return {color: '#fdae61'};
            case 'Letters':   return {color: '#fee090' };
            case 'Tippex':   return {color: '#ffffbf'};
            case 'Spray':    return {color: '#e0f3f8'};
            case 'Chalk':    return{color: '#abd9e9'};
            case 'Label maker sticker':    return{color: '#74add1' };
            case 'Poster':    return{color: '#4575b4'};
            }
      }
    return (
        <CircleMarker key={feature.properties.id} center={[coordinates[1], coordinates[0]]} pathOptions={markerStyles}>
            <Popup>
                <PopupContent content={feature} />
            </Popup>
        </CircleMarker>
    )
    }

    )
}
```

Additionally, it's not clear how to add additional events such as MouseOver and MouseOut, which I want to use as part of my UI. My ultimate goal was to add a LightBox to the images in my popups, but for now I'm stumped with conditional styling.

Comment: pathOptions need to be of type `PathOptions` and not a function as in your case.

Comment: is there any documentation on what the individidual layer types accept for `pathOptions`, because that function works on the GeoJSON layer component?

Comment: Yeah, geoJson can accept a styleFunction but not the other. https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/
The documentation on react-leaflet is a bit lacking. However its typed so you should be able to see the typing in you project. You can just ctr+cklick you way through and look up the types

Comment: Thanks, that seems really limiting between not being able to do popup components with GeoJSON and then no style functions on the circle markers...

Comment: I would say that it depends on the usage of said component. You can still pass PathOptions and change the color. 
If you want to have more options when it comes to the icon, you can use the regular marker and set whatever icon you want.

Comment: I'm trying to set the color of the individual markers by one of their feature properties. Icons I'm not interested in because of dealing with 1000's of markers and my experiments with canvas markers not working well.

Comment: You should still be able to set the color, see my answer below

Comment: awesome, I will have to test this tomorrow, but first look looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CircleMarker can still take a pathOptions which should be of the type:

```js
export interface PathOptions extends InteractiveLayerOptions {
    stroke?: boolean | undefined;
    color?: string | undefined;
    weight?: number | undefined;
    opacity?: number | undefined;
    lineCap?: LineCapShape | undefined;
    lineJoin?: LineJoinShape | undefined;
    dashArray?: string | number[] | undefined;
    dashOffset?: string | undefined;
    fill?: boolean | undefined;
    fillColor?: string | undefined;
    fillOpacity?: number | undefined;
    fillRule?: FillRule | undefined;
    renderer?: Renderer | undefined;
    className?: string | undefined;
}
```

So in this case just use the function that you already have:

```js
import { CircleMarker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import PopupContent from "./PopupContent";

const markerStyles = (feature) => {
  switch (feature.properties.type) {
    case "Sticker":
      return { color: "#a50026" };
    case "Mural":
      return { color: "#d73027" };
    case "Marker":
      return { color: "#f46d43" };
    case "Characters":
      return { color: "#fdae61" };
    case "Letters":
      return { color: "#fee090" };
    case "Tippex":
      return { color: "#ffffbf" };
    case "Spray":
      return { color: "#e0f3f8" };
    case "Chalk":
      return { color: "#abd9e9" };
    case "Label maker sticker":
      return { color: "#74add1" };
    case "Poster":
      return { color: "#4575b4" };
  }
};
const CircleMarkerLayer = ({ data }) => {
  return data.features.map((feature) => {
    const { coordinates } = feature.geometry;
    return (
      <CircleMarker
        key={feature.properties.id}
        center={[coordinates[1], coordinates[0]]}
        pathOptions={markerStyles(feature)}
      >
        <Popup>
          <PopupContent content={feature} />
        </Popup>
      </CircleMarker>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: is the top snippet using TypeScript?

Comment: The top snippet is the interface of PathOptions, directly copied from the types in react-leaflet